# Troubleshooting basic issues with orientjs (OrientDB driver for node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, orientdb, orientjs

I'm trying to test the latest version of orientjs with the 2.2 GA version of OrientDB. Using the very simple code below, I get no errors or exceptions, but also no output from the callback functions. I also don't see anything in the OrientDB server logs (which is running on the local server and is accessible via the web GUI).

```
var OrientDB = require('orientjs');

try {
  var server = OrientDB({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 2424,
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin'
  });
} catch(error) {
  console.error('Exception: ' + error);
}

console.log('>> connected');

try {
  server.list()
  .then(function(dbs) {
    console.log(dbs.length);
  });
} catch(error) {
  console.error('Exception: ' + error);
}

try {
  var db = server.use({
   name: 'GratefulDeadConcerts',
   username: 'admin',
   password: 'admin'
  });
} catch(error) {
  console.error('Exception: ' + error);
}

console.log('>> opened: ' + db.name);

try {
  db.class.list()
  .then(function(classes) {
    console.log(classes.length);
  });
} catch(error) {
  console.error('Exception: ' + error);
}

db.close()
.then(function() {
  server.close();
});
```

How do I go about troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: Have you tried an older version of ODB? In the PHP world, we also have issues with ODB 2.2, because the PHP driver hasn't been updated to the new binary protocol.

Comment: Thank you. And no, I didn't think of that. I assumed orientjs would be compatible with ODB 2.2. I'll try, but if that's the case, can someone from ODB confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think user and password are wrong.

Btw if you want to catch error you should use promises catch instead of try/catch block

```
  var OrientDB = require('orientjs');
  var server = OrientDB({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 2424,
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin'
  });

  server.list()
  .then(function(dbs) {
    console.log(dbs.length);
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.error('Exception: ' + error);    
  });
```

What happens with this script?

```
 var OrientDB = require('orientjs');
  var server = OrientDB({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 2424,
    username: 'root',
    password: 'root'
  });

  var db = server.use({
   name: 'GratefulDeadConcerts',
   username: 'admin',
   password: 'admin'
  });




  db.query('select from v limit 1')
  .then(function(results) {
  console.log(results)
    server.close();

  }).catch(function(error){
      server.close();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. In my actual code I'm using user/pass that I can successfully login into the web GUI with, so I think that part is OK. But if it weren't, I would expect to get an exception telling me that my login was unsuccessful. I did make the changes to use the promise catch, but the results are the same. I'm sure there's something I'm doing wrong, but with no response of any kind--good or bad--I don't know how to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: eric i've added a script. In my box it works. Can you try it?

Comment: I'll try it later today. By the way, what version of ODB are you using (that this script works on)?

Comment: OrientDB 2.2 and orientjs 2.2

Comment: OK. It's working now! Stupid mistake on my part: I had assumed that the promises would resolve after I called db.close() and server.close(), but instead they just executed immediately, effectively canceling my pending queries. Using your suggestion, I moved the server.close() call and got what I expected. Next step--brush up on promises. Thank you for your help!